# How to create a custom button which downloads a pdf report in odoo 13?

Tags: odoo, odoo-13

I want to create a custom button in the odoo employee model, which creates and downloads a pdf with the working contract of this employee. I tried to reverse engineer the given buttons in odoo, but every approach of mine failed. Does someone have a tip on where to start? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually return an [URL action](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/reference/actions.html#url-actions-ir-actions-act-url) with the download button, and write a [controller](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/reference/http.html) for the URL. The result is clicking the button actually downloading a file.

First step is to write your Qweb report. I'll write a sample one here. Note that the report ID is `action_report_test_contract` which is used later in the controller.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <report string="Test Contract" id="action_report_test_contract" model="hr.contract" name="your_module_folder_name.test_contract_report" file="your_module_folder_name.test_contract_report" report_type="qweb-pdf" print_report_name="'%s - Contract' % (object.name)" />

    <template id="test_contract_report">
        <t t-call="web.html_container">
            <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="doc">
                <t t-call="web.internal_layout">
                    <div class="page">
                        <h1><t t-esc="doc.name"/></h1>
                        <h2>Employee: <t t-esc="doc.employee_id.name"/></h2>
                        <h2>Start Date: <t t-esc="doc.date_start"/></h2>
                    </div>
                </t>
            </t>
        </t>
    </template>
</odoo>
```

Don't forget to add the report file path to your manufest. Test print the report from a contract, yes the sample works. Now inherit the `hr.employee` module to add the download method.

```
class HrEmployee(models.Model):
    _inherit = "hr.employee"

    def button_download_contract(self):
        if not self.contract_id:
            return
        return {
                'type' : 'ir.actions.act_url',
                'url': '/web/download/test-contract-report?contract_id=%s'%(self.contract_id.id),
                'target': 'self',
    }
```

Also, inherit the view to add the download button:

```
<button name="button_download_contract" type="object" string="Download Contract" icon="fa-download"/>
```

Finally, finish the controller:

```
from odoo import http
from odoo.http import request, content_disposition, route

class testDownload(http.Controller):
    
    @route(['/web/download/test-contract-report'], type='http', auth="user")
    def download_pdf(self, contract_id, **kw):
        employee_contract = request.env['hr.contract'].sudo().search([('id','=',contract_id)], limit=1)
        if not employee_contract:
            return None
        pdf, _ = request.env.ref('your_module_folder_name.action_report_test_contract').sudo().render_qweb_pdf([int(contract_id)])
        pdfhttpheaders = [('Content-Type', 'application/pdf'), ('Content-Length', len(pdf)),('Content-Disposition', content_disposition('%s - Contract.PDF' % (employee_contract.name)))]
        return request.make_response(pdf, headers=pdfhttpheaders)
```

Note that the method `render_qweb_pdf` relies on the report object. So `action_report_test_contract` is used, not `test_contract_report`.